# Unauthorized error using POST to get access token

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpclient

Trying to create a POST to get the access token with HTTP client and Basic authentication. I get the error unauthorized

Here is the simple code that I'm trying the use

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), _tokenUrl))
                {
                    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$_clientSecret:$_clientSecret"));
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Banner {base64authorization}");

                    request.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials&scope=bci");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    //var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                }
                return null;
            }
```

The documentaiton says

> To get an access token you need to make a POST request to
> `/as/token.oauth2` using the following
>
> - HTTP header: Content-Type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
> - Body: `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=bci`
>
> The request must be authenticated using HTTP Basic authentication and
> your `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET`

Comment: Not every authentication regime is the same and may differ widely from *internet cowboy web developer* to the next. What does the documentation say ?

Comment: To get an access token you need to make a POST request to /as/token.oauth2 using the following HTTP header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the following request body: grant_type=client_credentials&scope=bci The request must be authenticated using HTTP Basic authentication and your CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET.

Comment: Why you use "Banner" and not "Basic" on Authorization Header ?